# Strange email and phone call from company interested in interview. Is it a scam?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process

I have been applying for jobs and have uploaded my resume to public recruiting websites (e.g. [www.ziprecruiter.com](http://www.ziprecruiter.com)). The other day I checked my spam folder and found a new message. It was from someone trying to arrange an interview with me. It looked a little like spam and I decided to ignore it. The next day someone leaves a voice mail for me asking if I'm available for an interview. They said the company name very fast and slurred so I couldn't catch it. However, I looked up the phone number in my email and found it matched the email that was marked as spam. I've been trying to return the call but keep getting a voice mail. Here is the email bellow (with personal information changed)

> From: Jenny Adams [mailto:example1@gmail.com]  Sent: April 10,
>   2017 4:03 PM To: example2@gmail.com    Subject: ZipRecruiter
>
> Hello , Fin
>
> I reviewed your resume with my regional director, John Doe, and we
>   feel you have some valuable prior work experience that we wanted to
>   discuss in further detail. I am available to talk with you sometime
>   this week in the morning (excluding Thursday and Friday). Let me know
>   which day works best for you and I will schedule you in for a phone
>   meeting.
>
> Feel free to give me a call or text me at `555-86 <tel:555-223-1142> 7-8641`
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Sue Edwards, Human resources
>
> www.AILCareers.com http://www.AILCareers.com

I found John Doe on LinkedIn and they seemed legit, but I couldn't find another name. Also when I called and got the voicemail it only said the person's name but not the company. What should I do next? Can anyone tell if this is some kind of scam? Gmail's filter certainly thought so.

NOTE! The phone number appeared malformed, like a hyperlink to another phone number inside the one presented. This leads me to believe something is up.

Comment: It has every chance of being legit, but the verbiage is a little "funny."  Be prepared for it to be someone selling you "Executive Placement Services."

Comment: Unless you modified the names, its a scam. it starts `from jenny adams` and ends `regards, sue edwards` . it looks like their email bot isn't very well made. Even if it isn't a scam, a company that can't figure out email is probably one best avoided.

Comment: The OP said he changed all the personal information in the email text....

Comment: The fact that you got an email and phone call with the same information tells you that it's at least a real person and not just a spambot. Whether it's a legitimate company or not is another question.

Comment: If they're a legitimate business they aren't going to be using GMail addresses to mail you things.  This looks oddly like spam, actually.  Especially with differing phone numbers.

Comment: For the phone number issue you could just send a simple query "I'd like to phone you but the phone number hyperlink was malformed. Could you tell me your phone number in plain text please." - Observe how they reply to a simple query like this; if they are illegit you will soon know.

Answer (score 6):

The internet has tons of available information.

1. Reverse Lookup the number and see if it's legit
2. Lookup the company in question and see if you can find the person
3. Call the company and see if they have a company directory with the person who called
4. google the email address and the number and check for spam reports on the number
5. Lookup the name of the individual for social media or other sites

If the above indicates a legitimate company and person then just call them back and ask as it's probably a legitimate source and company.  Usually spam shows something fishy in the above and half the time it will show up on a reported number site as they don't just call 1 person and it's usually reported as a spam call online.

Answer (score 2):

Goto http://www.AILCareers.com . This is obviously a commission bases Insurance sales opportunity. it marked as spam because they email blast this kind email to everyone resume on any job board.

I can assure that "I reviewed your resume with my regional director, John Doe" is completely false. No reviewed your resume.

Is this a scam? I dunno, depends on your perspective. I don't think they are stealing from anyone.

PS: Note the About us section "American Income Life Insurance Company is striving to become the premier in-home life insurance sales company serving working families in the United States, Canada, New Zealand, and through our wholly-owned subsidiary, National Income Life Insurance Company, in New York."

Comment: This. Its not a scam, its a standard recruiter shotgun mail blast - its doubtful your CV was ever "reviewed" by anyone, they just want you on their books.  I get these all the time.

Comment: I'm unused to recruiters and do find they don't seem very focused on individuals they are contacting