# Never told location of interview and recruiter is unresponsive

Tags: interviewing, communication, hiring-process, recruitment

This follows up to [Strange email and phone call from company interested in interview. Is it a scam?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89123/strange-email-and-phone-call-from-company-interested-in-interview-is-it-a-scam) I received an email from a company that was interested in an interview with me. It was flagged as spam and had some odd parts to it (e.g. the phone number was malformed) but the next day I got a voice message from the same recruiter. After about a week of trying to get a hold of her I was able to and set up an interview for tomorrow. She said she will send me a confirmation email with the location but she never did (I checked the spam again). I've been trying to get a hold of her but it always goes to voice mail. At this point is there anything I can do? From recent experience, recruiters seem very unproductive and I'm surprised companies are switching to them.

Comment: Not sure what recruiter company and what country your in, but I have never had that bad of an interaction with an agency.  If it's not spam, I don't think they will do good business if they keep that up.  I'd say keep looking and if they pop back up keep trying to lock in an interview if your interested.

Comment: Time to move on; this recruiter sounds like too much effort, effort that you could use to look for other, more interesting opportunities.

Comment: Sounds like the recruiter was trying to squeeze an interview from the company without actually having one, then didn't succeed in securing one so has gone to ground.  Walk away and just deal with reputable recruiters.

Comment: @JaneS maybe, though she said she had a couple time slots and asked which I wanted.

Comment: It seems strange to me that you're investing so much time and thought in what sounds like a typical cold call. Have you had previous contact with this recruiter or did you approach them? In normal circumstances the SOP is for the recruiter to do the legwork if they approach you and for you to break contact as soon as they do something shady or go silent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the name of the company, call that company directly and explain to them that the recruiter is being terribly unprofessional and get them to look up the location of the interview. You'll need to give them what information you have available about the interview if it's a bigger company, and they might still not be able to figure it out. But a decent HR department should be able to find your interview location.

You should probably also stop working with this recruiter, as they are clearly incompetent. They're not all bad, so don't discard the whole idea, but you need to occasionaly get rid of a rotten apple.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't bother with the recruiter

Comment: I think it's likely that the company has likely never heard of the OP.

Comment: @JaneS In that case, you've lost the cost of a phone call. Seems worth a try at least; they might really be incompetent instead of malicious.

Comment: @Erik Oh, I totally agree with your answer and upvoted accordingly :) I just fear the OP shouldn't put much stock in an employment opportunity here.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly phrase it as the recruiter "being terribly unprofessional" when calling directly. Try to be professional by stating your side of the communication, e.g. by "double checking the facts somewhat unclear to you". They may jump to the conclusion of their colleague being unprofessional themselves.

Comment: @hardmooth I don't think this recruiter works for the company, but if they do you might want to tone it down indeed.